# Hugo builds files locally, but not on server

Tags: gulp, hugo

I'm using Hugo + gulp to build a static website. Locally, when I do npm start the site builds on my localhost. However, when I build via my server, only html is displayed. I get the following errors:

[Google developer tools error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEjIk.png)

I suspect an issue is that Hugo is not building all of my files, but I'm not sure if it's an issue regarding the server (Federalist) or my local code.

Local build :
 [Local Hugo -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVb1y.png)

Server build logs:

[Server Hugo -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q2ES.png)

Any leads or advice would be greatly appreciated :D!

Comment: Same error message (with potential fixes) here: https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/mime-type-text-plain-is-not-a-supported-stylesheet-mime-type-and-strict-mime-checking-is-enabled/16435/16